# Understanding question about function defined by integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

I've found this question on a paper and I have some difficulty understanding what exactly I'm asked to do.

> For each of the following functions $f$, if $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x} {f}$, at which points $x$ does $F'(x)=f(x)$ ?

- $ f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
  0,  & x \le 1 \\
  1, & x > 1
  \end{cases}$
- $f(x)=...$
- $f(x)=...$

But how can this not hold true for all integrable functions $f$, since by differentiating we get:

$F'(x)=(x)' \times f(x)-(0)' \times f(0)=f(x)$

Comment: Try integrating the first one (the one with the step discontinuity for $f$).  Can you draw the picture of $F(x)$? Then see what happens when you try to differentiate at certain points.

Comment: Clearly $ F'(x) =f(x) $ for all $x\neq 1$. And $F'(1)$ does not exist. All this is a direct consequence of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: I have discussed the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1900844/72031 and you may have a look at it.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I don't see how the FFTC clarifies if $F$ is differentiable at the points of discontinuity of $f$. How can we get information about this from the FFTC?

Comment: FTC does not say anything about points where $f$ is discontinuous. But the typical proof of FTC helps to know what happens when $f$ has a simple discontinuity (that is left and right limits of $f$ exist). Thus we have the result that if left hand limit $\lim_{x\to c^{-}} f(x) $ exists then left hand derivative of $F$ at $c$ is equal to this limit and similarly for right hand limits and right hand derivative.