# Is this function (discontinuous at one point) integrable?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Consider the function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(0)=0$ and
$$
f(x)=2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right).
$$
Is $f$ integrable on $[0,1]$?

Ps. Clearly $f$ is discontinuous at $0$ and it has primitive $F(x)=x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$. But I don't know whether $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=F(1)-F(0)=\sin 1$. Also, I would say that $f$ is integrable if and only if $g(x)=\cos(1/x)$ for $x>0$ and $g(0)=0$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ (since the remaining term is continuous on $[0,1]$).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is integrable, since it is bounded and the set of the points at which it is discontinuous has measure $0$.

Comment: We can apply monotone convergence theorem to find the value of the integral, right?

Comment: Yes. And you can also do$$\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\lim_{a\to0}\int_a^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\lim_{a\to0}F(1)-F(a)=F(1)-F(0),$$since $F$ is continuous.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos For the monotone convergence theorem, would you make the sequence $f_n(x) = f(x) \cdot X_{[\frac 1n, 1]} - X_{[0, \frac 1n]}$? (since $f \ge -1$ on $[0, 1])$.

Comment: @Ovi Yes, that would do.

Answer (score 2):

Because $F'(x)=2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$ for $x\ne 0$ and $F'(0)=0$ and that $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}|F'(x)|dx\leq 3<\infty$, $F$ is actually absolutely continuous, so $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=F(1)-F(0)=\sin 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the function $f$ in your question is bounded on any finite interval and is discontinuous only at a single point hence it is Riemann integrable on any closed interval.

And clearly you have found a primitive $F$ such that $F'=f$ everywhere thus by [second fundamental theorem of calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1900844/72031) $$\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx=F(b) - F(a) $$